# Completely new to x86 assembler, trying to use SSE

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

Okay, the last time I wrote a more-or-less useful piece of Assembler code lasts back in the mid 1980s, trying to make an Apple ][+ beep nicer...

What I want to achieve is to use the SSE extensions of my x86 processor. As an entry point, I've used the code the German Wikipedia provides. (Try searching for ''vector processor'' in the English version, then choose ''Deutsch'' as the language, then scroll down a bit.)

Here's the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mul_asm(float* out, float* in, unsigned int length)
{
    unsigned int count, rest;

    rest = (length * 4) % 16;
printf("rest: %i\n", rest);
    count = (length * 4) - rest;
printf("count: %i\n", count);
    if (count > 0)
    {
        __asm __volatile__(
            ".intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
            "loop:\n\t"
            "movups xmm0,[ebx+ecx]\n\t"
            "movups xmm1,[eax+ecx]\n\t"
            "mulps xmm0,xmm1\n\t"
            "movups [eax+ecx],xmm0\n\t"
            "sub ecx,16\n\t"
            "jnz loop\n\t"
            ".att_syntax prefix\n\t"
              : : "a" (out), "b" (in), "c" (count), "d" (rest): "xmm0", "xmm1");
       printf("\tcount: %i\n", count);
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int length = 8;

    float* out = malloc(sizeof(float) * length);
    if (out == 0) return 1;
    float* in = malloc(sizeof(float) * length);
    if (in == 0) return 1;
printf("So far so good...\n");
    out[0] = 1.0f; out[1] = 2.0f; out[2] = 3.0f; out[3] = 4.0f;
    out[4] = 5.0f; out[5] = 6.0f; out[6] = 7.0f; out[7] = 8.0f;
    in[0] = 1.0f; in[1] = 2.0f; in[2] = 3.0f; in[3] = 4.0f;
    in[4] = 5.0f; in[5] = 6.0f; in[6] = 7.0f; in[7] = 8.0f;
printf("outs and ins set.\n");
    mul_asm(out, in, length);
printf("Multiplied.\n");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("out[%f] = %f\n", (double)i, out[i]);
    }

    getc(stdin);

    free(out);
    free(in);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is happy when compiling the code with

```
gcc -O3 -msse2 -Wall -Wextra test.c
```

(-O3 to enable SSE)

But when executing the code, it gives "Speicherzugriffsfehler". like this:

```
So far, so good...
outs and ins set.
rest: 0
count: 32
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

(which is a memory access error.)

Again, I am a complete newbie to x86 Assembler coding. What am I missing?

Comment: For starters,if you want to write intel syntax assembly, you should use `-masm=intel` and not switch syntax behind the compiler's back. As for the fault, use a debugger. Also make sure you are not accidentally compiling as 64 bit. Add `-m32` if in doubt.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Which instruction does this crash at? What compiler version do you use? What operating system?

Comment: In the first iteration you access `in[length]` and `out[length]` which are one behind the last valid entry of the allocated arrays.

Comment: Using inline asm is [risky](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm). And there are [alternatives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.2/gcc/X86-Built_002din-Functions.html). But if you must, take time to read the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), including the part that says *Do not modify the contents of input-only operands.*